# parallel iterations in for loop in shell

Tags: shell, for-loop

I am trying to run a command across some lines in a text file. I am using for loop for this as below.

```
for LINE in `cat $LogDir/details.lst`
do
#Queue state dump
#The following amqldmpa command dumps the queue state every 10 seconds for one minute.
amqldmpa -m $QMGR -c A -u 1 -q $LINE -d 3 -n 6 -s 10 -f $LogDir/$LINE.txt
done
```

Now there are close to 20 lines in the details.lst file. How can i run this command against all these lines at the same time in parallel? Also how can i get out of the for loop only after all the lines have been successfully executed in the command?

Please help.

Comment: try `gnu parallel`: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- that's the wrong way to iterate over the *lines* of a file. Use this a while loop.
- put each amqldmpa in the background
- assuming your shell is bash, use the `wait` builtin

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    amqldmpa --options... &
done < "$LogDir/details.lst"
wait
echo "all jobs done"
```

You do lose the exit statuses of all the backgrounded jobs that way though.

Comment: Thanks, Glenn. This worked. I am wondering if it will work with my for loop too. One question i have is, how does wait work here? Does it wait automatically till all the jobs spawned by the while loop are completed? Do i need to check with something else to see if the jobs are completed?

Comment: Yes, `wait` with no arguments will wait for all background jobs to complete: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-wait